# Apostol section 13.25#18-conic sections

Tags: vectors, conic-sections

Consider the locus of the points X  in the plane for wich the distance of X from the point (2,3) is equal to the sum of the distances of X from the coordinate axes.
a) Show that the part of this locus which lies in the first quadrant is part of a hyperbola.locate the assymptotes and make a sketch.
b) Sketch the graph of the locus in the other quadrants.

ATTEMPT:a)
Let F=(2,3),Then for the first quadrant 
$\Vert X-F \Vert =x+y= \sqrt 2 (\frac {x-2}{\sqrt 2}+\frac {y-3}{\sqrt 2} +\frac{5}{\sqrt 2})$ This is a vector equation of a hyperbola of the form $\Vert X-F \Vert =e\vert (X-F)\cdot N+d\vert$.So
$e=\sqrt 2$,$X=(x,y)$ and $d=\frac{5}{\sqrt 2}$(d is the distance from the focus 
 F to the directrix),$N=(\frac {1}{\sqrt 2},\frac {1}{\sqrt 2})$ is the unit normal to the directrix L.F must lie on the  possitive part of the hyperbola determined by N.The transverse axis of the hyperbola has the same direction with N and includes F,So the equation of the axis must be x=y+1.If we choose an X wich lies on the axis and using the relations $\vert X-F \Vert=e d(X,L)$ and $  d=d(X,L)+\Vert X-F\Vert $ then we can find this X from  $d=\frac {\Vert X-F \Vert}{e}+\Vert X-F\Vert$.Now to find the center C of the hyperbola we use $(\Vert F-C \Vert -d)e=\Vert X-C \Vert $ (X is the X wich lies on the axis).
So $\vert \alpha \vert =\Vert X-C \Vert$ and $b=\vert \alpha \vert \sqrt {e^2-1}$.The assymptotes pass through the C and are the  hypotenuses of the two triangles with sides $\vert \alpha \vert$ and b on the two planes determined by the transverse axis.

QUESTIONS:
A)Is the solution correct;
As far as the b) part of the exercise I found $N=(\frac {-1}{\sqrt 2},\frac {1}{\sqrt 2})$ and $d=\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}$It seems the hyperbola described by this equation has most of its left part in the first quadrant.Propably  i must sketch only the points lying in the second quadrant.?If i got the hyperbola correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the question. Notice first of all that point $X$ exists only if $x+y\ge0$, i.e. if $X$ lies above the line of equation $y=-x$. In this case we can square equation $||X-F||=x+y$ to get
$$
(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=(x+y)^2,
$$
which is the same as
$$
(x+3)(y+2)={25\over2}.
$$
The latter is the equation of an equilateral hyperbola, with center at $(-3,-2)$ and asymptotes parallel to the coordinate axes. Its upper branch all lies in the region above line $y=-x$ and is the required locus, while its lower branch lies below that line and must be discarded.

Comment: First of all ,thank you for answering!In the book I am studying (Apostol Calculus volume 1)the standard form of the cartesian equation for conics is reffered ,I am aware there is a more general form but I have not studied it .The general equation for conics I know is the vector equation I tried to use.Is the equation you wrote a general cartesian equation for a hyperbola?How did you find the assymptotes?Thank you again.I am trying to find how can I derive the general cartesian equation from the vector equation.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the equation I wrote is a modification of [the simplest hyperbola equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Hyperbola_with_equation_y=A/x), namely: $xy=A$. This is a rectangular hyperbola, having the cartesian axes as asymptotes and the origin as center. If we perform a translation carrying the center to $(a,b)$, then its equation becomes $(x-a)(y-b)=A$. I think you can of course use your "vector equation" if you like, but at the expense of more cumbersome computations.